# Spring MVC file upload via MultipartFile gives sometimes(!) empty InputSteam

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, apache-commons-fileupload, apache-commons-io

we encountered a strange problem with our simple file upload system.

The setup is: Spring 3.2.2, commons fileupload 1.3, commons io 2.4. We're actually running straight from Eclipse with an external Tomcat 7.0.40. It's been tested on Mac OS X 10.8 and 10.6.

Here's the code:

```
public void saveFile(MultipartFile file, String description) {
    System.out.println(file.getOriginalFilename());
    System.out.println(file.getSize());
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("someFileName");
    IOUtils.copy(file.getInputStream(), out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

It outputs the correct file name *and also the correct file size*!

Now when it comes to writing the file to disk, it produces a 0 byte file. This especially happens with `.docx` files (in about 95% of the cases). It seems to depend on the file. Images and PDF documents seem to work always.

There's no exception or any other hint. **The debugger says that the `InputStream` is empty (not `null`, just empty).**

Any explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: i'm encountering a similar problem, did u manage to solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I would check the following:

- Does your server has any antivirus / malware software that prevents unknown program to write docx into the filesystem.
- Does the OS user that runs your server (hence writes the file to FS) has sufficient permission to do so?
- InputStream empty could means the uploaded document starts with EOF. Also check the content of the docx itself maybe it's corrupted / some file encoding problem causes multibyte character interpreted as EOF. I would probably debug the docx by printing first few bytes in hex

Comment: it's no permission problem, since everything works with images and pdf. And even *some* docx are working nice, but most of them just get saved as 0 byte files. And I don't think that there is any anti virus software. At least on my dev system there is none and the problem remains.